# Connecting to an existing db farm using MonetDBLite C API

Tags: monetdblite

I have a DB farm created with a database (ex: temp). When I try to connect to that using monetdb_startup, get the following error.

> src/gdk/gdk_utils.c:1465: GDKfree: Assertion `(asize & 2) == 0' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

1. I'm using the sample application tests/readme/readme.c provided.
2. monetdb_startup("/dbfarm/temp", 0, 0) is what I'm trying to do.
3. Monet version being used: 
   MonetDB 5 server v11.29.3 "Mar2018" (64-bit, 128-bit integers)
4. Stack trace:

   ```
           #0  0x0000003f39232495 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
           #1  0x0000003f39233c75 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
           #2  0x0000003f3922b60e in __assert_fail_base () from /lib64/libc.so.6
           #3  0x0000003f3922b6d0 in __assert_fail () from /lib64/libc.so.6
           #4  0x00007ffff799bc3c in GDKfree (s=0x19602e0) at src/gdk/gdk_utils.c:1465
           #5  0x00007ffff79a8521 in freeException (msg=0x19602e0 '▒' <repeats 88 times>, "▒L\001") at src/mal/mal/mal_exception.c:135
           #6  0x00007ffff7b38c09 in SQLupgrades (c=0x7ffff42b2400, m=0x1815460) at src/mal/sqlbackend/sql_upgrades.c:1442
           #7  0x00007ffff7b1edb2 in SQLinitClient (c=0x7ffff42b2400) at src/mal/sqlbackend/sql_scenario.c:612
           #8  0x00007ffff7404f32 in monetdb_connect () at src/embedded/embedded.c:72
           #9  0x00007ffff74055da in monetdb_startup (dbdir=0x7fffffffd7c0 "/dbfarm/temp/", silent=0 '\000', sequential=0 '\000')
               at src/embedded/embedded.c:162
   ```

Thanks

Comment: So the database was created using MonetDB, and you are trying to connect to it with MonetDBLite?

Comment: yes. on debugging, found that there was an exception(parse error) when executing the method sql_update_mar2018, particularly when executing, i guess are, meta data sqls. 
I avoided calling sql_update_mar2018 and it worked. I am able to see the tables in existing dbfarm. But not sure about this solution.
if it helps, I can get the exact stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this use case is not supported. So upgrade MonetDBLite databases between versions should work fine, but moving from MonetDBLite to MonetDB and back is probably going to give errors and/or crash.